# How to structure large number of unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust

I have a Rust project that has several modules. I've been adding a module called tests where I put my unit tests but I've gotten to the point where testing needs a significant amount of scaffolding and I believe that will add a lot of noise to the code base. Is there a way to move my tests elsewhere, perhaps to a tests.rs file?

Comment: Rust is still in development and best practices are evolving. I asked the same question on reddit and got a significant number of upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Cargo supports running tests from `tests/` subdirectory. You can find a reference to this (though rather brief) in the [Cargo guide](http://crates.io/guide.html). In short, you can separate tests from your main source tree by placing them in sources in `tests/` subdirectory of your project. These tests are just normal Rust sources (with `#[test]` annotations), so you need to `extern crate` your crates to test them there. This supports writing *integration* tests, not *unit* tests.

Unit tests are usually written in `#[cfg(test)]`-marked submodules of the module under test. They are able to access non-public items of their enclosing modules, so this is ideal for unit testing.

There is also a [recent change](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/435) in Cargo which allows something even more powerful, but I'm not sure how it should be used exactly.

Comment: That change allows for the external tests to be arbitrary binaries, i.e. just a `main`, not `#[test]`s (with pass/fail based on the return code).

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2epnmn/how_to_organise_tests/ck2gaws